# How to develope a decision tree with only buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

i want to create a decision tree where in the start page you have 3 Buttons you can choose between
after you click on one of the three buttons you will be lead to a question where you have to answer with yes or no( also Buttons ).

Now the question.

How do i create the different scenarios?
Is it possible to create different "Screens" and then connect the screen to the button you click?

Like on click you route to this screen?

Has someone some advice for me.

On figma i created different screens and linked it with an on click action.
As you can see here:
https://www.figma.com/proto/WAXaZLHTVetIs1TNRoJHYM/Emergency-Sheet?node-id=1%3A4&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%253A1&starting-point-node-id=1%3A4

Comment: Are you using node and/or any frameworks or just vanilla html/css/js? Do you want it all to be a single html page or multiple pages?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Personally, I would solve it with an `object` (mutable data type to store a collection data) and dynamically create the screens by looping through with a `for`-loop.

Comment: @Simp4Code multiple pages would make it way harder and be super inefficient as you need to run server-sided or use localStorage instead of simply generating the element dynamically.

Comment: @tacoshy it depends on OP’s skill level. Multiple pages and then just some anchor tags is the easiest way, as inefficient as it may, this might be comfortable for the OP

Comment: @Simp4Code I would probably use node.js but need to do some research how it works. I would prefer the easiest option. Im good with Java but its my very first time web app project

Comment: like I said, the easiest option would be an array/object and then a for-loop. However, you should at least add more details and clarity like a list of questions and answers

Comment: @Identicon how well do you know JS?

Comment: @tacoshy i added the link of the whole application i need in figma to make more clear what i am looking for.

Comment: @Simp4Code im getting used to Javascript by now still a beginner but i understand it. 

So the best solution is to change the website by itself with every click?

Comment: @Identicon yeah, there are several ways to approach this. I'm thinking to have all your questions in full width/height sections which live just outside the viewport using CSS. Then using JS you could add an active class the relevant section to bring it into viewport, this would be triggered on click of the relevant buttons -- I'll put together a basic answer to point you in the right direction

Comment: Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) -> This means that if you rely on Figma to ask your question then it would not fit the SO guidelines. Add the details in the question itself!

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully point you in the right direction

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('goTo'));

buttons.forEach( button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const gotoId = button.getAttribute('data-goto');
    
    const currQuestion = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
    const nextQuestion = document.getElementById(gotoId);
    
    currQuestion.classList.add('visited'), currQuestion.classList.remove('active');
    
    nextQuestion.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }
body { margin: 0; text-align: center }

#questions {
  display: grid;
  block-size: 100vh;
  inline-size: 100vw;
}
.question {
  grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1;
  
  transform: translateX( 100% );

  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.question.visited { transform: translateX( -100% ) }
.question.active { transform: translateX( 0 ) }

.buttonList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<div id="questions">

  <!-- FIRST QUESTION -->
  <div class="question active" id="system">
    <h1>Emergency Contacts</h1>
    <p>Select where the emergency occured</p>
    <button class="goTo" data-goto="infrasys">Infrasys(POS)</button>
    <button class="goTo" data-goto="shiji">Shiji SEP(PMS)</button>
    <button class="goTo" data-goto="kiosk">Kiosk</button>
  </div>


  <!-- Infrasys Questions -->
  <div class="question" id="infrasys">
    <h2>Infrasys</h2>
    <p>Choose the problem</p>
    <div class="buttonList">
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="infrasys-p1">Problem 1</button>
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="infrasys-p2">Problem 2</button>
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="infrasys-p3">Problem 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="infrasys-p1">
    <h3>Infrasys Problem 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="infrasys-p2">
    <h3>Infrasys Problem 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="infrasys-p3">
    <h3>Infrasys Problem 3</h3>
  </div>


  <!-- Shiji Questions -->
  <div class="question" id="shiji">
    <h2>Shiji</h2>
    <p>Choose the problem</p>
    <div class="buttonList">
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="shiji-p1">Problem 1</button>
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="shiji-p2">Problem 2</button>
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="shiji-p3">Problem 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="shiji-p1">
    <h3>Shiji Problem 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="shiji-p2">
    <h3>Shiji Problem 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="shiji-p3">
    <h3>Shiji Problem 3</h3>
  </div>


  <!-- Kiosk Questions -->
  <div class="question" id="kiosk">
    <h2>Kiosk</h2>
    <p>Choose the problem</p>
    <div class="buttonList">
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="kiosk-p1">Problem 1</button>
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="kiosk-p2">Problem 2</button>
      <button class="goTo" data-goto="kiosk-p3">Problem 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="kiosk-p1">
    <h3>Kiosk Problem 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="kiosk-p2">
    <h3>Kiosk Problem 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="question" id="kiosk-p3">
    <h3>Kiosk Problem 3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW!!! I dont know how to thank you but holy you helped me so much!!!!

Comment: @Identicon no worries, if there’s anything you need me to change or if you have any questions about the code just let me know. This was the easiest way I could think to do it, you may still get other answers that are more efficient or something but if you’re happy with this then accepting my answer and an upvote would mean a lot! Good luck and take care